# How to generate URL in ASP.NET / C# for a Single Sign-On (SSO) using JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, single-sign-on

> I have the following code that serialize a JSON string:

```
    string token = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()); // token creation
    DateTime Minutes = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25);
    StringEncryption stringEncryption = new StringEncryption();
    var sso = "MY_SSO_KEY";

    OnlineProfile onlineProfile = new OnlineProfile();

    onlineProfile.first_name = "John";
    onlineProfile.last_name = "Doe";
    onlineProfile.email = "johndoe@multisite.com";
    onlineProfile.expires = Minutes.ToString();
    onlineProfile.url = "https://www.multisite.com";
    onlineProfile.SSO = stringEncryption.Encrypt(sso);
    onlineProfile.signature = stringEncryption.SignData(token);

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
    serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, onlineProfile);

    }
```

> The code above generates the following JSON data output:

```
    //{"email":"johndoe@multisite.com",
    //"expires":"10/11/2018 14:25:00 PM",
    //"first_name":"John",
    //"last_name":"Doe",
    //"url":"https://www.multisite.com",
    //"SSO":"MY_SSO_KEY_ENCRYPTED",
    //"signature":"TOKEN"}
```

> And with that JSON data would like to form the following url:

```
http://www.multisite.com/sso?sso=MY_SSO_KEY_ENCRYPTED&signature=TOKEN
```

> How can I form the url above? Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try the UrlBuilder

[try the UrlBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)